# ElasticSearch: How do I delete index entries from head?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to delete index entries directly from MOBZ's ElasticSearch head (web UI).

I tried a DELETE query in the "Any Request" section with the following:

```
{"query":{"term":{"supplier":"ABC"}}}
```

However, all I get in return is:

```
{
ok: true
acknowledged: true
}
```

and the entries do not get deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have removed the "query" from your post data.
You only need it for _search, and you should be using the _query entrypoint for delete.
In that case it is obvious the post is only a query, thus making it redendant (and actually irrelevant) to explicitly state it's a query.

That is:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/mydoc/_search' -d 
'{"query":{"term":{"supplier":"ABC"}}}'
```

will work fine for search.
But to delete by query, if you try:

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/myindex/mydoc/_query' -d 
'{"query":{"term":{"supplier":"ABC"}}}'
```

it won't work (note the change in entry point to _query, as well as switch CURL parameter to delete).
You need to call:

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/myindex/mydoc/_query' -d 
'{"term":{"supplier":"ABC"}}'
```

Let me know if this helps.

If you want to do it in HEAD:

1. put `/stock/one/_query` in the any request text box next to the drop-box of "GET/PUT/POST/DELETE"
2. choose DELETE in the drop-down menu
3. the request body should be `{"term":{"vendor":"Socks"}}`

Your problem was that you used a request body of: `{"query":{"term":{"vendor":"Socks"}}}`
That is fine for search, but not for delete.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback. I actually deleted all index entries with the first command I described above. Here is a sample index entry:
`{
_index: stock
_type: one
_id: FT7h2uaap7WO6r5NfjEiRNyElys=
_version: 1
_score: 1
_source: {
pid: 28690 # 116983767
title: Ladies 3 Pair 
description: Get the classic Pringle look 
price: 7.00
brand: Pringle
vendor: Socks
}
}`

So what I am trying to do is just delete all entries where the VENDOR value is "Socks" and only using the HEAD interface (so no CURL instructions)

Comment: If our answers helped you, please vote them up and/or accept one.

Regarding "no curl" you should really get to know translating between HEAD (which is awesome) and curl, as you'll get much more help online that way, and most documentation for ES is in curl format...

as far as your question, I've edite the response, let me know if that helped clear things up.

Comment: FYI sense will convert both ways for you.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense/doinijnbnggojdlcjifpdckfokbbfpbo?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to delete from plugin head by doc Id:

1. Go to Any Request TAB in plugin head
2. Simply put `http:/localhost:9200/myindex/indextype/id` in the text box above DELETE drop-down
3. Select **DELETE** from drop-down
4. Execute the request by clicking in Request button

Here is the sample image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd issue a search request first, to verify that the documents you want deleted are actually  being returned by your query.

It's impossible to give clear help, since there are many things that could be going wrong, but here are some possible probelems:

- You don't have the correct index/type specified in the ES Head query
- You need to specify the index and type on the second input box, not the first.  The first line is meant for the host address and automatically adds a trailing slash
- You need to use the Delete command from the dropdown
- The analyzer of your fields is altering the field text in a way that it isn't being found by the Term query.

In all likelihood, it is the last option.  If you haven't specified an analyzer, the default one that ES picks is the Standard analyzer, which includes a lowercase filter.  The term "ABC" is therefore never indexed, instead "abc" is indexed.

Term query is not analyzed at all, so case sensitivity is important.

If those tips don't help, post up your mapping and some sample data, and we can probably help better.